# Will US Customs and Border Protection allow my girlfriend (UK Citizen) to come help me recover from surgery (covid-19)?

Tags: usa, uk, covid-19, travel-ban

Earlier this year she did a 14-day layover in Bermuda to travel from the UK to the US and that worked fine. She wants to come back in November to help me recover from surgery. I have a letter from the doctor's office.

Anyone heard of people doing this in past few months?

Comment: Will she be coming directly from the UK or will she again spend 14 days in a non-banned country first?

Comment: @user102008 Ideally directly from the UK, Bermuda was a hassle

Comment: If you are recovering from surgery you probably don't want someone who might be infected with covid near you.

Answer (score 2):

Your girlfriend cannot enter the USA directly from the UK at present, according to the [UK government travel advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa).

We can't say whether that will change before November, but given the current pandemic situation in Britain I'd say it's unlikely.